# Delete n% of the rows from the excel sheet on click of the button using VBA or any excel formula if possible

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel, vba7

I want to delete the n% of the cells from the sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4. The percentage will be given in the sheet name as raw. For example in raw sheet in E19 its given 10%, so in every sheet S1,S2,S3,S4 it should delete the total of 10% of the rows of data. (example: sheet 1 have 100 rows with data so as per 10% it should delete the 10 rows from 100 rows and similarly for other sheets as well. I have researched alot but did not get anything relevant to this.

Answer (score 2):

To delete the first x percent of the lines you can do it like this:

```
s.Range(s.Cells(1, 1), s.Cells(s.UsedRange.Rows.Count * Range("Percentage").Value, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Where the range ("Percentage") is the cell where your percentages are given

To get it for all sheets, you just need a loop to repeat that:

```
Sub deleteFirstPercentageOfRows()
Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Name <> "raw" Then
            s.Range(s.Cells(1, 1), s.Cells(s.UsedRange.Rows.Count * Range("Percentage").Value, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```